# Как использовать strripos php с регулярным выражением

Tags: php

У меня есть строка

```
$current_product_name = "Русский текст";
```

При выводе на фронт мне нужно подсветить русские символы
пробую это

```
$haystack = $current_product_name;
$needle   = "/^[^а-я]+$/";
$pos      = strripos($haystack, $needle);
$current_product_name = str_replace($needle, '<span data-marker>' . $needle .'</span>', $haystack);
```

Вопрос как использовать Регулярку для needle

Или возможно есть другая функция для этого

Comment: Для этого есть функции работы с регулярными выражениями, в частности `preg_replace`/`preg_replace_callback`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то вам примерно такое нужно

```
$str = "abc йцу asd фыв zxc";

$result = preg_replace_callback("/[а-яё]+/iu", function($m){
                return "<mark>{$m[0]}</mark>";
            }, $str);
            
echo $result;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]